# HttpClient is making my RAM & CPU in fire

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, cpu, ram

I'm making a lot of post requests using the method below, and at a moment it's making my program crashing because the RAM/CPU use is too high (100%).

This is my current code :

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy, false)
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
};

HttpClient proxyClient = null;
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = webProxy,
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
};

proxyClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

return proxyClient.PostAsync(targetURL, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is what I lastly tried (instead of `return proxyClient.PostAsync...`) :

```
string request = proxyClient.PostAsync(targetURL, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

proxyClient.Dispose();
httpClientHandler.Dispose();

return request;
```

I can't figure out why, after multiple searches.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read this [article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) about properly usage of HttpClient.This article also describe some performance problems that might be useful for troubleshooting your problem

Comment: @ArturLavrov Hello, I looked into it and it doesn't helped me fixing anything :/

Comment: As @ArturLavrov mentioned you should not be creating a new Http client everytime, you should have 1 that you reuse. The most used methods on HttpClient are all thread safe

Comment: @StéphanieAutire try to use shared singleton instance of HttpClient. And when you try to make a request, use this instance instead of creating new one

Comment: @ArturLavrov How can I do it ? I've never done it before :/ Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

StéphanieAutire, it's vital to note that your implementation could be different. You also could create a pool of reusable instances.But the general idea could be expressed in this code.

```
public sealed class HttpService
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient instance = new HttpClient();

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static HttpService()
        {
        }

        private HttpService()
        {
        }

        public static HttpService Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to leave here some useful references that helps you to find more information about this topic and implement that solution that exactly satisfy you needs.

**References**

[Correct way of using HttpClient](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/correct-way-of-using-httpclient)

This answer could be a good guide in this problem.Check it first.